# How to join a dataframe and dictionary on two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, join

I have a dictionary and a dataframe. The dictionary contains a mapping of one letter to one number and the dataframe has a row containing these specific letters and another row containing these specific numbers, adjacent to each other (not that it necessarily matters).

I want to update the row containing the numbers by matching each letter in the row of the dataframe with the letter in the dictionary and then replacing the corresponding number (number in the same column as the letter) with the value of that letter from the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [7, 8, 9]]))

dict = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5}
```

Let's say dict is the dictionary and df is the dataframe I want the result to be df2.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[3, 2, 5], ['b', 'a', 'c'], [7, 8, 9]]))
```

df

```
   0  1  2
0  4  5  6
1  a  b  c
2  7  8  9
```

dict

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}
```

df2

```
   0  1  2
0  2  3  5
1  a  b  c
2  7  8  9
```

I do not know how to use merge or join to fix this, my initial thoughts are to make the dictionary a dataframe object but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Whats the logic of this join? You replace the first rows with the values of dict matching the second row with the keys?

Comment: Are you only interested in numeric rows that have an alphabetic row after them? Or, are you literally only interested in one particular row in your particular case? I ask because you seem to be treating a row of data like a column. IOW, you'd usually expect to find a 'letters' column in an example like this. For example, all of your column `dtype`s will be `O`, for object, because they have mixed types.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I appreciate the help. @Erfan the logic is I have updated values for the column corresponding to the value of row x but I want to update the value in row y where row x is a key of the dictionary and row y is the value of the dictionary. What you said is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Mike I generalized this case but in the actual case for me yes I have mixed type columns so I am have generated new values that are stored in the dictionary and I want to update them in the data frame where a key is a string and the value is a numeric value if that clarifies it?

Comment: Sure. My only concern was that maybe you were using pandas sideways, basically. Like, if I had `df.columns == ['num_potatoes', 'weeks_since_stubbed_toe', 'book_is_read']`, I'm not sure I could imagine a row operation that would make sense on a particular *row* that crossed those *columns*, since columns are for data categories and rows are for instances. Anyhooo, if my answer is what you need, could you accept it? It helps everyone when you do. If not, could you comment why? I may be able to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little weird, but:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [7, 8, 9]]))
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[1].map(lambda x: d[x] if x in d.keys() else x)

df
#    0  1  2
# 0  2  3  5
# 1  a  b  c
# 2  7  8  9
```

I couldn't bring myself to redefine `dict` to be a particular dictionary. :D

After receiving a much-deserved smackdown regarding the speed of `apply`, I present to you the theoretically faster approach below:

```py
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[1].map(d).where(df.iloc[1].isin(d.keys()), df.iloc[0])
```

This gives you the dictionary value of d (`df.iloc[1].map(d)`) if the value in row 1 is in the keys of d (`.where(df.iloc[1].isin(d.keys()), ...`), otherwise gives you the value in row 0 (`...df.iloc[0])`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It turns out I was using Pandas sideways in my head. How would I modify this to work on mapping a dictionary to two columns?

Comment: Fitting a complete answer into a comment won't be easy, and would be less searchable for others than if you were to create a new example and question. I'll probably see it, though you could ping me here when you're done, too. Though, now I think about it, you should be able to get there from here, not least with a bit of research. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , "Search, and research")